checks.state argument is missing | openid-client
const params = client.callbackParams(req);
const code = params.code;
const userState = params.state;
const clientId = process.env.ROBLOX_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.ROBLOX_CLIENT_SECRET;

console.log(params)
if (toString(userState) === toString(state)) {
    try {
        const tokenSet = await client.callback('http://localhost:3000/callback', params)
        console.log(tokenSet)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
};

So, I'm  trying to get the token but I getting this error:
TypeError: checks.state argument is missing

But when printing the params I getting this output:
{
  code: '-6Z59VCNmyTEN_2LKT8zsN5lgBp7tXOkuzs5hv9yLYfGhn7-A5rKTXCRTF_58vLhtVcug7-SPvzSnDkGUm2TuL21SsE1SRWB0u-Ioo9IiY_40CkoxQdWghkgBxEeJDk6mZhDJ0DCK1tjSVC3U5dy7UsBrUqKdWJ-8YMJ7FoRMf_CnycPOV6rPWeCc4onbAs1cckAbvie5jOyHRponvnOwSwU-KhxKoGrFhsCkIT-EtO3766Q3nwaYveS5-o0AcTt',
  state: 'JFjqMHGIdy8wf7Y56HF5-VHbuZlY_ENMMdwlMkRCpzY'
}

So I really don't know how the state argument is missing if its litralry there...

Did you find a solution for this?

Looks like you've missed the checks object.  Try:
const tokenSet = await client.callback('http://localhost:3000/callback', 
                   params, { state: userState })

As per https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/blob/main/docs/README.md#clientcallbackredirecturi-parameters-checks-extras

state:  When provided the authorization response's state parameter will be checked to be the this expected one. Use of this check is required if you sent a state parameter into an authorization request.

